# Woocommerce subscriptions, remove first payment date on cart and checkout pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, subscription

I would like to remove (not just hide) the first payment date on the cart and checkout pages because it's very confusing for my client.
I don't find where and how to override the html output.

The information is added from a woocommerce subscription function (wcs-cart-functions.php) as following:

```
function wcs_add_cart_first_renewal_payment_date( $order_total_html, $cart ) {
    if ( 0 !== $cart->next_payment_date ) {
            $first_renewal_date = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), wcs_date_to_time( get_date_from_gmt( $cart->next_payment_date ) ) );
            // translators: placeholder is a date
            $order_total_html  .= '<div class="first-payment-date"><small>' . sprintf( __( 'First renewal: %s', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), $first_renewal_date ) .  '</small></div>';
        }

        return $order_total_html;
    }
    add_filter( 'wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'wcs_add_cart_first_renewal_payment_date', 10, 2 );
```

For obvious reasons, I don't want to modify the core files.

What I've tried is to add a display:none in my theme CSS. It works but it just hides the information.

```
.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table .first-payment-date {
    display: none;
}
```

Thank you for your clues and ideas.
Fred

Answer (score 0):

Well, as no one seems to have reached my question, I answer to myself with not a cleanest solution (in my opinion) and hoping there is no hidden side effect.
I override the core function by creating a new one by reseting the html output:

```
/* Hide information of first payment date by override order_total_html output  */
add_filter( 'wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'hide_first_renewal_payment_date', 100, 2 );
function hide_first_renewal_payment_date( $order_total_html, $cart ) {
    $order_total_html = '';
    $value            = '<strong>' . $cart->get_total() . '</strong> ';
    // If prices are tax inclusive, show taxes here
    if ( wc_tax_enabled() && $cart->tax_display_cart == 'incl' ) {
        $tax_string_array = array();

        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) == 'itemized' ) {
            foreach ( $cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) {
                $tax_string_array[] = sprintf( '%s %s', $tax->formatted_amount, $tax->label );
            }
        } else {
            $tax_string_array[] = sprintf( '%s %s', wc_price( $cart->get_taxes_total( true, true ) ), WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $tax_string_array ) ) {
            // translators: placeholder is price string, denotes tax included in cart/order total
            $value .= '<small class="includes_tax">' . sprintf( _x( '(Includes %s)', 'includes tax', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), implode( ', ', $tax_string_array ) ) . '</small>';
        }
    }

    $order_total_html .= $value;
    return $order_total_html;
}
```

I'd be glad if someone could point me to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Copy that function to your function.php file and give it a different name (I added '_custom' to mine). Make whatever changes you want to it.

Then add the following filters into function.php ...

```
// This removes the default function
remove_filter( 'wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'wcs_add_cart_first_renewal_payment_date', 10, 2 );
```

```
// This runs your version of the function (Note that I'm calling the new '_custom' function) 
add_filter( 'wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'wcs_add_cart_first_renewal_payment_date_custom', 10, 2 );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try this solution.